Getting 400 Error, while generating random numbers in Excel VBA
This VBA code is working perfect if numCells ie (ActiveSheet.Range("W2").Value) is greater than 8, Like (9, 10,15, 20 etc). But, if my numCells valueis less than 9 (Like 8, 7, 6, 5, 4 etc), it's giving a 400 error.
Sub Generate_Random_Value()
Dim total As Double
Dim numCells As Integer
Dim minValue As Double
Dim maxValue As Double
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Integer

' Define parameters
total = ActiveSheet.Range("T2").Value
numCells = ActiveSheet.Range("W2").Value
minValue = ActiveSheet.Range("U2").Value
maxValue = ActiveSheet.Range("V2").Value

' Clear existing values in the range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("E9:E" & numCells)
rng.ClearContents

' Generate and distribute random numbers
Randomize ' Initialize the random number generator
For i = 1 To numCells - 1
    Set cell = rng.Cells(i, 1)
    cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(minValue, maxValue)
    total = total - cell.Value
Next i
' The last cell gets the remaining value to ensure the sum is equal to total value (Target Value).
rng.Cells(numCells, 1).Value = total

End Sub

If numCells denotes number of cell should be: Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("E9:E" & numCells +8) or Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("E9").Resize(numCells)

Generate Random Integers

Main
Sub GenerateRandomIntegers()

    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    ' Retrieve arguments.
    Dim Total As Long: Total = ws.Range("T2").Value
    Dim MinValue As Long: MinValue = ws.Range("U2").Value
    Dim MaxValue As Long: MaxValue = ws.Range("V2").Value
    Dim IntegersCount As Long: IntegersCount = ws.Range("W2").Value
    
    With ws.Range("E9") ' references the top cell
        ' Populate.
        PopulateColumnOfRandomIntegers .Cells, IntegersCount, MinValue, MaxValue
        ' Clear below.
        .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row - IntegersCount + 1) _
            .Offset(IntegersCount).ClearContents
        ' Append totals adjacent to the bottom of the integers.
        .Offset(IntegersCount) = Application.Sum(.Resize(IntegersCount), Total)
    End With
    
End Sub

Help
Sub PopulateColumnOfRandomIntegers( _
        topCell As Range, _
        IntegersCount As Long, _
        MinValue As Long, _
        MaxValue As Long)

    Dim Data() As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To IntegersCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To IntegersCount
        Randomize ' Docs: "Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)"
        Data(r, 1) = Int((MaxValue - MinValue + 1) * Rnd + MinValue)
    Next r
    
    topCell.Resize(IntegersCount).Value = Data

End Sub

